# How to make Facebook Audience Network as primary ad network in Facebook mediation bidding Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Network in my application I don't want to use other ads networks. but Facebook introduces mediation bidding. In official documents of Facebook Audience Network they give us the option "only use audience network not bidding" when I choose this option Facebook did not give any ads response.
If I use mediation then I want to use Audience Network as my primary ad network, not another network.
Please help me if anyone has any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time and many experiments, I found some solutions to handle this situation.

1. First you can't add FAN as Primary Network. if you create ads id in `Waterfall`, not in `mediation`, and implement directly you will see in the Facebook console "bidding request" option. Facebook says "Not gets bidding request" it will not activate ads in your application.
2. If you want FAN as your Primary Network firstly you should do Mediation when facebook activate your request ads then shift to waterfall it will give you ads
3. In my case I have to implement Admob ads with the mediation of Facebook and FAN ads separately and control them with Firebase Remote Configuration. Now you have implemented two Ads SDK first is AdMob and the second is Facebook. When Facebook accept bidding request from AdMob then you just change ads from Admob to Facebook via Firebase Remote Configuration. Basically, you have two SDK implementations in your app.
4. This solution is for when you got limitations from Admob and want to run Facebook ads. Remote configuration is the best solution for the limitation of Admob networks. you can also remove limitations from AdMob by using different ads network and controlling them via remote configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some third party mediation like Ironsource as they provide you this functionality. Please check.